# Centering a div when divs above and below it change sizes

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

Okay, so I'm using the Ionic Framework and I have two cards(divs). Think of the cards as questions that you're supposed to select. Between these cards I want the word "or" to be perfectly center even when the size of the card changes due to text content. Is there a way to keep this "or" perfectly centered using css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting your cards above and below the word or, you can do this easily with flexbox.  Just wrap all three divs in a container and set the container to `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column`,and `align-items: center`.  All three will be put in a vertical column and be centered with each other.  From there you can limit the width by setting a width on the container if you so choose.  No matter how small or big the text in the two cards get 'or' will be nice and centered between them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("button").click(function() {
    $.get("http://lorem.mannfolio.com/", function(data) {
      var lorem = data.split("\n\n");
      $("#card-one").html(lorem[0]);
      $("#card-two").html(lorem[1]);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<button>Change text</button>
<div class="container">
  <div id="card-one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div>or</div>
  <div id="card-two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, obcaecati!</div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create another specific width `div` in between with margin on top and bottom and centered the *Or* text using `margin: 0` auto or `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.div1{
width:45%;
float:left:
}
 .divmiddle{
width:10%;
float:left:
}
 .div1{
width:45%;
float:left:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all three divs inside a containing div, and style it with flexbox:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
align-items: center; /* align vertical */
```

You have more information about this (and other options) [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css?rq=1).